# All Hyperledger Fabric (v 1.4.2) peers crash when network goes down

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, docker-swarm

I created a distributed network using docker swarm. Peers of org2 in host2 and peers of org1 in host 1. When one of the host loses its connection, all the peers crash. I think this is because, the overlay network is removed until the other node comes back online. Is it normal for the peers to crash. When I checked the logs for the peers, This is the error that is common to all the peers.

```
panic: runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference
[signal SIGSEGV: segmentation violation code=0x1 addr=0x0 pc=0xaed020]

goroutine 164 [running]:
github.com/hyperledger/fabric/protos/gossip.(*SecretEnvelope).InternalEndpoint(0x0, 0x40c445, 0x7f7bdc461c30)
    /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/protos/gossip/extensions.go:480 +0x40
github.com/hyperledger/fabric/gossip/discovery.newAliveMsgStore.func4(0x1243280, 0xc0043abd10)
    /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/gossip/discovery/discovery_impl.go:1032 +0xfd
github.com/hyperledger/fabric/gossip/gossip/msgstore.(*messageStoreImpl).expireMessages(0xc0003fa800)
    /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/gossip/gossip/msgstore/msgs.go:212 +0x34c
github.com/hyperledger/fabric/gossip/gossip/msgstore.(*messageStoreImpl).expirationRoutine(0xc0003fa800)
    /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/gossip/gossip/msgstore/msgs.go:253 +0x141
created by github.com/hyperledger/fabric/gossip/gossip/msgstore.NewMessageStoreExpirable
    /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/gossip/gossip/msgstore/msgs.go:53 +0xb2
```

The goroutine number is different: for eg: on another peer, it'll be "goroutine 44 [runnning]:"

If all peers are crashing, the service would be denied which is bad. isn't it? When the network is back, shouldn't the peers take care of itself.

If this is expected behaviour, what is the minimum number of hosts i must use to keep the network on. Right now i'm using two computers connected to wi-fi. Sometimes the connection the wi-fi goes and comes back. Also note that none of the other services like the ordering service, certiface authority crash. Only the peers crash.

All the crashed peers have to be manually restarted using docker start [containerid]

Comment: I believe this has been reported here -> https://jira.hyperledger.org/browse/FAB-16054 and here https://jira.hyperledger.org/browse/FAB-16292 for 1.4.2 - as an interim measure you may want to try 1.4.1 ?

Comment: @PaulO'Mahony Yea!! You're right!! Just came across it now.. Thanks man. I'll try 1.4.1. I read jira.hyperledger.org/browse/FAB-16292 [here] that 1.4.3 will release by end of August.